# Mongo DB privileges to insert data in a specific database?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, privileges

I'm fighting to get my MongoDB container to work with authentication.

I created a database, and a user on that database with the **dbAdmin** role. But it seems this role is not enough to be able to insert data to the database, because when I run a script which populates my DB, I get this kind of error message:

```
error: not authorized on mydb to execute command { insert: "attachs", documents: 59, writeConcern: { getLastError: 1, w: 1 }, ordered: false }
```

So I guess I need to add some other privileges for my user, but I can't figure out which are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.createUser({
          user : "root",
          pwd : "root",
          roles : ["readWrite", "dbAdmin"]

});
```

You can create a role with **readWrite**. It will work.

Comment: Thanks @Mehraj, I'll try this asap.

Comment: It works, but not with this syntax, the good one is: db.createUser({ user: 'user', pwd: 'blablabla', roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "thedb" }, {role: "dbAdmin", db: "thedb"} ] });

Comment: The syntax in the answer is correct, just that it should be executed in the same database ('use db') to which you intend to create the user on. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/#roles

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above answer, for an existing user, you can use the [db.grantRolesToUser()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.grantRolesToUser/) command to assign it **readWrite** role. E.g.

```
use test
db.grantRolesToUser("user1", [ "readWrite"] )
```

Above grants user1 the readWrite role on the test database. I wrote a [step by step tutorial](https://hubs.ly/H09j0WZ0) on how to grant privileges to roles and roles to users recently. It might be useful.